# Plot split date/time over night (instead 0 - 24 hours, 12 - 24 and 0 - 12)

Tags: r, time, plot

I need an idea how to split a plot which goes from 0 to 24 hours into 12 to 24 and 0 to 12. As a result I want to have the middle of the night in the middle of the plot.

```
# sample data
date <- strptime(paste0("2014-",c(rep(sample(90:300, 100),4))), "%Y-%j")
h <- c(rep(paste(sprintf("%02d",as.numeric(sample(c(0:7,22:23))), 10),
             sample(10:59, 50),sep=":"),8))
# plot data
hour <- strptime(paste(date, h), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
time <- difftime(hour, date , units="hours")
startMonth <- as.POSIXct(as.Date("2014-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"))
endMonth <- as.POSIXct(as.Date("2014-12-31", format="%Y-%m-%d"))
plot(x=date, y=time, xlim=c(startMonth, endMonth), ylim=c(24, 0) )
```

At the moment the result looks like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rqu1.png

My aim is it that the the midnight line is in the middle of the plot. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot(x=date, y=time - 24 * (time > 12), 
     xlim=c(startMonth, endMonth), ylim=c(12,-12), 
     yaxt = "none",
     ylab = "time")

breaks <- pretty(range(12, -12))
axis(2, at = breaks,
     label = breaks + 24 * (breaks < 0 ))
```

[image: resulting plot]